# Installing a SSL certificate to a Domain Hosted in AWS

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services

I have domain **example.lk** hosted in Amazon AWS. And I want it to be accessed (only) using **HTTPS**. In other words I want to redirect all my traffic to the website http://example.lk to https://example.lk

I have searched the web alot and all the different solutions are confusing me. THe last approach I tried was

1. Created a Certificated in AWS Certificate Manager
2. Created a Load Balancer to my EC2 Instance and associated the certificate
3. Added a A Record to the Hosted Zone.

Since I have the nginx server running as my web server I have modified the config file for my website to

```
server {

    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 default_server;
    #ssl on;
    listen [::]:80;

...
}
```

When I try to go to **https://example.lk** It gives a

> SSL connection error

I know this question sounds like a broad one, But I am really clueless here. can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need an `ssl` keyword on your `listen 443` directive for a start. [Read this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Comment: I tried that as well. I still don't understand how the certificate created in AWS is linked to the nginx.

Comment: @RichardSmith Not if he terminates TLS at the elastic load balancer.